# Invoke dependent library's method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an iOS SwiftUI app with three targets - an app target and 2 static libraries (as shown below)

```
Project Workspace
--AppTarget 
----(some files)
--EntryPoint (static library)
---- <Struct conforming to App protocol>.swift
---- AppDelegate.swift
---- (other files)
--Experience (static library)
---- ContentView.swift
---- (other files)
```

For some reasons, the hierarchy is defined as follows:

```
// AppTarget depends on EntryPoint and Experience
AppTarget -> EntryPoint, Experience 

// Experience depends on EntryPoint
Experience -> EntryPoint
```

EntryPoint library has the entry point of the app i.e., a struct conforming to the App protocol. The body property must be a Scene, which must contain a View. The problem is, View is defined in Experience... and because Experience depends on EntryPoint, I can't mark Experience as a dependency for EntryPoint and do the following

```
import Experience
```

in the EntryPoint target as that would cause cyclic dependency error.

SwiftUI expects the Views inside the Scene to be known at compile time.

Questions:

1. How can I make the following code compile?

```
@main
public struct ProjectApp: App {

    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor
    private var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    
    public var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView() // ERROR
        }
    }
    
    public init() {
        
    }
}
```

ContentView is defined in Experience but I can't import Experience as it is a higher library. From what I gathered, there are no externs or forward declarations in Swift.

2. The Experience library has some stuff to do in the application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) launch delegate method. The AppDelegate is defined in the EntryPoint. How can I even invoke a method of a higher library (Experience) from a lower library (EntryPoint) in Swift?

Comment: Just write an additional library that has everything Experience and Entry Point depends on, so that they don't have to depend on each other. They will both depend on the additional library instead.

Comment: @Sweeper, that's not possible :(. If it were, there wouldn't be a need to have 2 different libs... The Views and its data might as well be defined alongside the App protocol... as shown in Xcode's default template. It has to be this way... Can this setup somehow work? Any Swift/SwiftUI feature I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps a design technique commonly used to invoke higher library's funcs from a lower library?

Comment: You need to refactor to remove the transitive dependencies.  Perhaps expose the things that `AppTarget` needs from `Experience` via `Entrypoint`.  Then `AppTarget` depends on`Entrypoint` and `Entrypoint` depends on `Experience`.

Comment: @Paulw11 But that would put `EntryPoint` above `Experience`. Along with `App` protocol conformer, `EntryPoint` has other basic blocks used through out the higher libraries... `Experience` is just one of those higher libraries, which unfortunately has some code (the `ContentView`) to be invoked by lower library.

Comment: What can I say? Your architecture has circular dependencies.  You need to eliminate them.  I think your fundamental issue is probably putting the `App` in a library rather than in the app target.